# How do I remove the dashed border on previously selected desktop icon on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons, appearance

Title is very informative in fact. When you select an icon and then click on the desktop, the previously selected icon remains in a non-focused selection mode which consists in it having a dashed/dotted border around it.

How to go over that, I don't want that border!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging out and logging back in or rebooting?  It seems to occur (or at the very least, I can replicate it) only after using Shift+Click to select multiple icons on the desktop.

Logging out and logging back in (or restarting explorer) seems to stop this behavior from happening.

Comment: That seems to work for now, but there should be a way of avoiding it from coming back. Anyway, thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

Is that a feature of your theme perhaps?

I don't get that with my desktop.

Comment: Everything is out-of-the-box so I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, there's this option under *Appearance > Effects*:

> Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key

It controls not only the underlines in menus, but also the "focused item" border you see.

I do not have Windows 7 available, but I'm sure there should be a similar option - maybe under Accessibility?

Answer (score 0):

The latest Nvidia display drivers fixed it for me.